Series with a half-dragon main character, talking swords, and planes
The series is cantered around two characters with more focus placed on the male mc than the female. The male mc is 50% dragon and 50% human (but we don’t find out till later), he’s a pilot in the military before higher ups find out about his magical abilities (which in this world are only possible through a draconic heritage of some kind) and he gets sent off to train under the wife of one of his superiors. Said superior and his wife also have a talking sword with a girl inside it that can use fire magic independently and who communicates via telepathy. The male mc later on also gets a similar sword with an old man who can use lightning magic (he steals it from a pirate on an island). The first book’s cover (i think, it might actually be the cover of one of the other books i’m not sure) shows the male mc and the female mc facing the reader while there is a dragon/serpent behind them also facing the reader.
Note:
This series had 5 books the last time i read it, and is a sequel to another series that’s focuses on that superior of the male mc and his wife. I never read it but from the synopsis of the series that i read it seemed to focus on how the superior and his wife met and fought off a dragon invasion or something and eventually fell in love (enemies to lovers or something cuz the wife is half dragon also and dragons are evil here)
Plot summary:
Male mc is a pilot who finds out he can do magic, then during an attack on his military base by a dragon he uses telepathy or something to help out and gets noticed by a superior who has a fire magic using telepathic sword with a girl’s soul inside. There’s a whole ass training and mission completing bit where mc learns from the superior’s wife and takes the fire girl sword with him on missions and then somehow they end up infiltrating a pirate island and find the old man lightning sword. That’s about as much as I can remember of the plot of the first book.
also, the cover for the fifth book (at least ONE of the covers for the fifth book) DEFINITELY is the female mc riding a dragon in the sky, with both facing the reader. Funnily enough, I remember the fifth book ended with the female mc asking male mc (after he found out and learnt how to transform into his dragon form (perks of being a half dragon)) if she could ride him, and him implying his assent in both the sky and in bed.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

Is it possible this is the "Heritage of Power" series by Lindsay Buroker?  It follows the "Dragon Blood" series and some of the same characters carry over.
The main character is the half-dragon (son of gold dragon Agarrenon Shivar) Telryn Yert, and the female sidekick is Rysha Ravenwood.  The sentient sword is Jaxi.
Actually the covers of the first four books show Rysha and Terlyn with a dragon behind them, though the closest to your description (them facing the viewer) is the fourth:
    
